Ion FAB button issue after build
[this image shows a screenshot with the correct FAB button in local modethe second image shows the same FAB button not showing correctly in production modeI'm developing a PWA displaying a MapBox map and my FAB button is not showing: instead, the four buttons inside the FAB appear but completely misshaped. Locally, everything looks good but the build damages everything.
I tried playing with the CSS but it ain't helping.

You need to share a minimal reproducible code, as its difficult to check anything by an image. Also a single image has been added in the question. It would be good if you will add the actual code and will create a reproducible example for the same.

thank you @YashMaheshwari, i just coded my own buttons, i didn't want to wait...
